# Unable to retrieve decryption key while decryt saml assertion

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are using itfox library for creating saml response. Assertion is encrypted successfully with relying party public key certificate. But on decryting saml assertion with relying party private key certificate, getting below error
Unable to retrieve decryption key while decryt saml assertion.

Answer (score 0):

First, the DecryptionCertificate is added in the Saml2Configuration and it is required that the certificate have a private RSA key.

Maybe the problem is that the process hosting the ITfoxtec Identity SAML library do not have access to the certificates private key? If the certificate is installed in Windows certificate store on a server the process needs to be given access to the private key. Also, if deployed in an Azure App Service access to the certificate is configured.